# The concurrent.blocking in future not work as expected in some scenario

Tags: scala, akka, future

Help to explain 2 phenomenon for scala future(Bold in code4 & code5), thanks.

***Code1***

```
package com.tst
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
      for (i <- 1 to 6) {
        Future {
          println("start")
          Thread.sleep(30000)
          println("end")
        }
      }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor])
  myActor ! 'msg
}
```

For code1, as my cpu core is 4, so at first 30 seconds, we can just see 4 `start` print, no problem for me. (If your cpu has more cores, e.g. 8 core, you may change the loop from 6 to 10 to reproduce my question)

***Code2***

```
package com.tst
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Future, blocking}

class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
      for (i <- 1 to 6) {
        Future {
          blocking {
            println("start")
            Thread.sleep(30000)
            println("end")
          }
        }
      }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor])
  myActor ! 'msg
}
```

For code2, as `blocking` is added, additional threads was employed, so we can see 6 `start` print at first, no problem for me.

***Code3***

```
package com.tst
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Future, blocking}

class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
      for (i <- 1 to 6) {
        Future {
          blocking { // lineA
            println("startpre")
            Thread.sleep(30000)
            println("endpre")
          }
        }
      }

      Thread.sleep(2000)

      for (i <- 1 to 6) {
        println("+")
        Future {
          blocking { // lineB
            println("start")
            Thread.sleep(30000)
            println("end")
          }
        }
      }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor])
  myActor ! 'msg
}
```

For code3, we can see 6 `startpre` & 6 `start` print at first 30 seconds, no problem for me.

***code4***

Just delete lineA in code3, the output is:

```
startpre
startpre
startpre
startpre
+
+
+
+
+
+
```

***This is my first question: why I can just see 4 `startpre` at first 30 seconds? Why `blocking` in lineB not work here? With my understanding, I should also see 6 `start`***

***code5***

Just delete lineB for code3, remember to undelete lineA if you delete it in code4, the output is:

```
startpre
startpre
startpre
startpre
startpre
startpre
+
+
+
+
+
+
start
```

***This is my second question: here there is 1 `start` be seen, but all 4 threads has been occupied, and 2 additional thread was launched for lineA's Future, why still one thread left for lineB to print 1 `start`?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681389/use-case-of-scala-concurrent-blocking) it is described good at my point of view.

Placing part of code in `blocking` notify execution context that some other thread result could be required to complete this blocking. So could be reasonable to run another thread to complete speedup evaluation.

In other words in your case `code4` 4 threads are busy with execution of `Futures` from first loop, they are not marked as `blocking` so no reason to add another working thread in pool, and, so, no thread to execute any new `Future` from second loop.

In `code5` all threads are busy with `Future` marked as `blocking`. Additional thread was started, occupied with `Future` from another loop without `blocking` so no reason to add one more thread.